# html How to allow to select only one <select multiple> from two

Tags: html, multiple-select

I have got two multiple selects, say multiple `select1` and multiple `select2`.

Multiple `select1` allows you to select from a list of websites and Multiple `select2` allows you to select from a list of different set of websites.

I just want to allow selection from only one of them and not both. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can disable one when the other is selected. Do it with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Got it with this:

`onchange="document.getElementById('abc').disabled=true;"`

Answer (score 0):

Select is used for getting multiple inputs from user.
If you only want to get one input from user,
Then use of radio button is the best way to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
<input type="radio" name="website" value="www.google.com" checked>     GOOGLE.COM<br>
<input type="radio" name="website" value="www.yahoo.com"> YAHOO.COM<br>
<input type="radio" name="website" value="www.bing.com"> BING.COM
</form>
</body>
</html>
```